# Pair to tuple.. (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, tuples

I want to have a function like

list :: [(Char, Int)]

to make all possible pairs (Tuple) between 1-10 and A-J

(Output: A1, A2, A3, ... J9, J10)

But I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[(a,b) | a <- "ABCDEFGHIJ", b <- [1..10]]
```

Your declaration will look like:

```
list :: [(Char, Int)]
list = [(a,b) | a <- "ABCDEFGHIJ", b <- [1..10]]
```

Comment: Thank you! And what should I enter in the script, that a specific word (e.g. "list") is enough to give out the pairs? (I hope you know what I mean)

Comment: @haskellnoob Are you using **ghci**, the interactive environment? If so, simply typing "list" will print its value.